# Read from randomly named text files

Tags: powershell, foreach

I'm finishing a script in PowerShell and this is what I must do:

- Find and retrieve all .txt files inside a folder
- Read their contents (there is a number inside that must be less than 50)
- If any of these files has a number greater than 50, change a flag which will allow me to send a crit message to a monitoring server.

The piece of code below is what I already have, but it's probably wrong because I haven't given any argument to `Get-Content`, it's probably something very simple, but I'm still getting used to PowerShell. Any suggestions? Thanks a lot.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp_erase\PID -Directory -Filter *.txt |            
ForEach-Object{
    $warning_counter = Get-Content
    if ($warning_counter -gt '50')
    {
        $crit_counter = 1
        Write-Host "CRITICAL: Failed to kill service more than 50 times!"
    }
}
```

Comment: `[int]$warning_counter = Get-Content $_.FullName` since you have not told it what to open. That is of course assuming you can guarantee that the file only contains that one line that has only a number

Comment: Thanks @Matt , I ran the code and it asks me to supply values for the parameter `process` of the cmdlet `ForEach-Object`, so I probably messed up somewhere else as well. Do you have any idea what it might be? Cheers

Comment: Move `foreach-object {` up behind the pipe on the first line

Comment: Fixed it :) Thanks! How can I select your answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but it's probably wrong because I haven't given any argument to Get-Content

Yes. That is the first issue. Have a look at `Get-Help <command>` and or [docs like TechNet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) when you are lost. For the core cmdlets you will always see examples.

Second, `Get-Content`, returns string arrays (by default), so if you are doing a numerical comparison you need to treat the value as such.

Thirdly you have a line break between `foreach-object` cmdlet and its opening brace. That will land you a parsing problem and PS will prompt for the missing process block. So changing just those mentioned ....

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\temp_erase\PID -Directory -Filter *.txt | ForEach-Object{
    [int]$warning_counter = Get-Content $_.FullName
    if ($warning_counter -gt '50')
    {
        $crit_counter = 1
        Write-Host "CRITICAL: Failed to kill service more than 50 times!"
    }
}
```

One obvious thing missing from this is you do not show which file triggered the message. You should update your notification/output process. You also have no logic validating file contents. The could easily fail, either procedural or programically, on files with non numerical contents.